# Como mostrar en un Datagridview una lista de objetos a elegir en un ComboBox (con diferentes listas como opciones)

Tags: c#, combobox

tengo diferentes listas de diferentes objetos y un `ComboBox` con los nombres de cada listas.

¿Como puedo hacer para que cada vez que elijo el nombre de una lista el `Datagridview` muestre la opción elegida?

Con `DataSource` solo puedo seleccionar una, en cuanto intento meter condicionales para las distintas selecciones del `Combobox` ya no me muestra nada.

Lo he intentado con esto para probar si puedo elegir entre estas dos listas pero lógicamente no funciona....

```
            cmbEntidades.Items.Add("pelicula");
            cmbEntidades.Items.Add("libro");


            if (cmbEntidades.Text == "libro")
            {
                i = librosPorDefecto();
                dgv1.DataSource = listaLibros;

            }
            else if(cmbEntidades.Text == "pelicula")
            {
                i = peliculasPorDefecto();
                dgv1.DataSource = listaPeliculas;
            }
```

Gracias!!!

Comment: En el evento selectedIndexChange del ComboBox podrías cambiar el dataSource del grid, edita tu pregunta para colocar tu código y así te podremos ayudar con mas detalle. Que a oscuras es muy difícil.

Comment: Intenta creando dos datagridview, y con la Propiedad ComboBox.SelectedIndex escoges cual activar. pero como te comentan, si muestras tu código nos podemos hacer una idea mas fácil, saludos.

Comment: Es winforms o asp?

Comment: Es windows forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hermano en el combo hay un evento llamado **selectedIndexChange**

que lo encontratas cuando pones clic derecho a tu combo  y opción propiedad

ahora en tu combo tienes que colocarle la propiedad AutoPostBack**AutoPostBack="true"**

ejemplo :

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="CboEstadoCivil" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" tittle="Seleccione estado civil" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CboEstadoCivil_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>




 protected void CboEstadoCivil_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(cmbEntidades.SelectedItem.Text=="libro")
{
 i = librosPorDefecto();
                dgv1.DataSource = listaLibros;
}
if(cmbEntidades.SelectedItem.Text=="pelicula")
{
  i = peliculasPorDefecto();
                dgv1.DataSource = listaPeliculas;
}
            }
```

Comment: Dado que el OP habla de `DataGridView`, dudo que su pregunta sea sobre asp.net, sino sobre winforms.

Comment: @Pikoh gracias modificare mi rspta

Comment: Perfecto! pero he tenido que eliminar el ".Text" para que funcionase. Gracias!!

Comment: El problema que veo ahora es que cuando recargo una lista por segunda vez me aparecen los elementos duplicados y si la vuelvo a cargar triplicados... No se si tiene que ver con el AutoPostBackAutoPostBack="true" que comentas, pero no lo encuentro por ningún lado

Comment: @dobarqueiro eso era para web form   en tu grilla para que no veas la duplicidad agrega esto : AutoGenerateColumns="False"

Comment: @dobarqueiro ejemplo : <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table toggle-arrow-small table-hover table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">

Comment: Pero eso que pones no es para webform tambien?